# Blend tool not working on converted objects from Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, blending-objects

This is an ultra novice question from an ultra novice person.

I created three overlapping vector paths in Photoshop then applied gradients to them. When I opened the PSD file in Illustrator, I chose "Convert Layers to Objects" then OK. Now, when I choose any two paths in Illustrator, click the blend tool and click on the paths so I can blend their gradients, nothing blends. The paths retain their colors.

What seems to be wrong here and what can I do so I can blend the gradients of the paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the use of the gradient overlay in Photoshop.
If I understand your situation correctly the layer panel of your `psd` file in PS looks something like this:

[image]

Importing that file in Illustrator and chosing `Convert Layers to Objects` would result in the following layer panel in AI:

[image]

Selecting one of the objects and checking the `Appearance` panel shows that the objects are not actual paths, but Illustrator sees them as images:

[image]

You can't work around this if you want to stick to making your gradient in Photoshop and exporting it to Illustrator. As Scott mentions in the comments the gradients in PS are raster images, not vectors.

The best thing would be to make the whole path and gradient in Illustrator. If the path's are complex you can export them from PS to AI without a fill, apply the gradient in AI and then do a blend.

Comment: thanks. i applied the gradient in illustrator instead of photoshop. blend is now working. :)